# opencv Viz3d and Qt widgets gui

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, vtk

I use QVTKWidget (application use Qt GUI, VTK and opencv) to visualize some mesh, but for certain reason best choice for me is use Viz3d. Is any solution to embed Viz3d windows to Qt gui based on widgets? Look like we need separate thread for Viz3D loop and forward keyboard and mouse event, didnt it? Can anyone have an example?

Comment: QVTKWidget is deprecated, you may want to move to QVTKOpenGLWidget.

Comment: I know. And this is one of the reasons why I want to switch to Viz3D. QVTKOpenGLWidget not suit for me.